# How to optimize my site for Google if I host complete english content on a .de url?

Tags: seo, html-heading

In a hosting package I have a free url, yet specifically .de ending (German). I now want to do a website under this url with complete english (US) language content. Only one language: english.
Is there a way to avoid ranking damage because of the „wrong“ url ending?
What can I do in my webpage headers?

Is:

```
<meta name="Content-Language" content="EN-US">
```

sufficient or can I do anything else?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Google uses the content of the page to determine its language, but the URL itself provides human users with useful clues about the page’s content. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en also, google will ignore that meta name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you using german domain.However my opinion is use any other domain or it will be helped to you to SEO purpose,A German site has German keywords obviously and you should have these words in your Url if you want an optimized site. if you can best thing is use `.Com`

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! I have only english keywords, meta description, content etc. Except the url ending. It is because it is part of my hostage package and therefor is free. If the SEO damage is too big I will have to get new hosting. But I am not an SEO expert so I simply don’t know.